# ¿Como cerrar modal en bootstrap desde JS?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, modal

Primera pregunta y principiante en la programación, desde ya agradezco su disponibilidad y paciencia.

Estoy realizando con un modal en *Bootstrap* la aceptación de *cookies*, obtuve un código que me facilita el registro en el *localStorage*, pero al momento de confirmar si ya se ha aceptado en un pasado no logro esconder la ventana modal y siempre se vuelve a mostrar al recargar la web.

Adjunto el código para ver si es posible que me ayuden.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    let cookies = () => {
        //======================================================================
        // COOKIES
        //======================================================================

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // Variables
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        let seccionCookie = document.querySelector('section.cookies');
        let cookieSi = document.querySelector('.cookies__boton--si');
        let cookieNo = document.querySelector('.cookies__boton--no');

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // Funciones
        //-----------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Método que oculta la sección de Cookie para siempre
         */
        function ocultarCookie() {
            // Cierra el modal de cookies automaticamente
            $('#modalOneModal').modal('hide');
        }

        /**
         * Método que marca las cookies como aceptadas
         */
        function aceptarCookies() {
            // Oculta el HTML de cookies
            ocultarCookie();
            // Guarda que ha aceptado
            localStorage.setItem('cookie', true);
            // Tu codigo a ejecutar si aceptan las cookies
            ejecutarSiAcepta();
        }

        /**
         * Método que marca las cookies como denegadas
         */
        function denegarCookies() {
            // Oculta el HTML de cookies
            ocultarCookie();
            // Guarda que ha aceptado
            localStorage.setItem('cookie', false);
        }

        /**
         * Método que ejecuta tu código si aceptan las cookies
         */
        function ejecutarSiAcepta() {
            async; src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-177632652-1"
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'UA-177632652-1');
            /////////////////// Tu código ////////////////
            ////////////  ¿Google Analítics? /////////////
        }

        /**
         * Método que inicia la lógica
         */
        function iniciar() {
            // Comprueba si en el pasado el usuario ha marcado una opción
            if (localStorage.getItem('cookie') !== null) {
                if (localStorage.getItem('cookie') === 'true') {
                    // Aceptó
                    aceptarCookies(

                    );
                } else {
                    // No aceptó
                    denegarCookies();
                }
            }
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // Eventos
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        cookieSi.addEventListener('click', aceptarCookies, false);
        cookieNo.addEventListener('click', denegarCookies, false);

        return {
            iniciar: iniciar
        }
    }

    // Activa el código. Comenta si quieres desactivarlo.
    cookies().iniciar();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código es correcto, pero no la lógica:

- **No mostrar el modal** hasta que hayas realizado validaciones
- Buscar *cookie* en *localStorage*
- Si no existe:

  - **Solo aquí se muestra modal**
  - Con los botones ya controlas lo que se debe hacer después
- Si existe:

  - Tiene valor 'true': Ejecutar funciones que usan *cookies*
  - Tiene otro valor: No ejecutar funciones que usan *cookies*

```
function iniciar() {
    // Comprueba si en el pasado el usuario ha marcado una opción
    let acepta = localStorage.getItem('cookie');
    if (acepta === null) {
        // Todavía no ha aceptado o denegado cookies
        $('#modalOneModal').modal('show');
    } else {
        // Ya aceptó o denegó cookies
        if (acepta === 'true') {
            // Aceptó, no es necesario mostrar modal, solo ejecutar funciones
            ejecutarSiAcepta();
        } else {
            // No aceptó, no usar cookies, es decir, no hacer nada
            // denegarCookies();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por el aporte entendí la corrección en la lógica. Y ahora esta funcioanndo!